# How to use Ctags with C++ trailing return types

Tags: c++, c++11, vim, ctags, trailing-return-type

I've come to like `C++11 style` trailing return types, however when I wanted to use `vim` with my C++ program I noticed that ctags don't mix well with them.

I've tried *exuberant ctags* and *universal ctags* and both don't seem to work with trailing return types.

Is there some way to configure `ctags` to cooperate with trailing return types?

Comment: Trailing return types are a legacy niche. In C++14 you'd simply use *no* manual return type in those cases where a trailing return type would be useful.

Comment: Report this issue in Universal Ctags GitHub page, I'm sure you'll get a reply.

Comment: I've done so, it seems they are working on it.

Answer (score 0):

The latest Universal ctags can extract the name and the return type of a function with trailing return type:

```
auto f(void) -> int
{
    return 0;
}
$ ~/bin/ctags --version
Universal Ctags 5.9.0(cbdc5c4b6), Copyright (C) 2015-2022 Universal Ctags Team
Universal Ctags is derived from Exuberant Ctags.
Exuberant Ctags 5.8, Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Darren Hiebert
  Compiled: Jun 20 2022, 00:48:48
  URL: https://ctags.io/
  Optional compiled features: +wildcards, +regex, +iconv, +option-directory, +xpath, +json, +interactive, +sandbox, +yaml, +packcc, +optscript, +pcre2
$ ~/bin/ctags -o - /tmp/foo.cpp 
f   /tmp/foo.cpp    /^auto f(void) -> int$/;"   f   typeref:typename:int
```